# UBUNTU-18.04.1 Desktop-amd64

Tags: system-installation, dvd

I have downloaded the ISO from the website and have burned a DVD disc.
I now want to load UBUNTU onto my PC and do not know how to proceed, please help.

Comment: You can google and follow steps from there, that will be more quick.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to boot from DVD and follow installation steps. If you want dualboot with windows - you should make free space on hdd, where you create partition for ubuntu. To resize windows partition you may choose "Try ubuntu without installing" from dvd boot menu, then run gparted and resize windows partition with it, and create ubuntu partition (ext4)- then reboot to dvd again and choose install. In installation process choose that new partition for install.

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0

> In this tutorial, we're going to install Ubuntu desktop onto your
>   computer, using either your computer's DVD drive or a USB flash drive.